# Wordpress host with raspberry pi - images don't load when accessing it from outside the network

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, raspberry-pi, web-hosting

I'm trying to make my first basic web server to host a wordpress website using a Raspberry pi 3, nginx, php7.0, mysql and phpmyadmin.

I have set everything all right, I can access the wordpress site and edit it when I'm connected to my router, but once I try to access it from outside using my phone network, it loads but it shows no images and the website looks totally disorganized.

I'm using no-ip to get a static IP, I have set the router DMZ on the Pi and it's connected through WiFi, so there should be no firewall between the Pi and my phone.

I really don't get why this is happening, it looks like something is blocking some parts of the info exchange, could this be my ISP and the solution would be to change the website port from 80 to another one? I'm starting to discard this option because when I access from outside to the phpmyadmin management site, it loads correctly, including all images.

As I said this is my first experience and I don't know what else to look, I would really appreciate help from more experienced users.

Comment: Spelling, grammar, readability, removed thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses two configuration variables to determine the address of the site and the address of resources for the site. See [changing the site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for details.

You currently have these values set to an internal address that cannot be resolved to your static IP.

If you set the values to your external address (used by your phone network to access the website), the external access should begin to work, e.g. `http://example.ddns.net/`. However, a negative side-effect is that internal access may stop working!

You should be able to make both internal and external access work, by removing the scheme and hostname from the values, and setting only the path component, e.g. `/`.